# "DATA_RETRIEVAL" error when deployed on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the new iOS SDK and it's associated REST API. Implementing the iOS framework was a charm but when trying to verify the payments using a Java/Google App Engine backend things are less than optimal. All of this is in testing on the sandbox environment.

Right now the Credit Card payment verification is working (using the REST API SDK v0.5.2) when testing locally. However, when I deploy the application to the app engine the call to com.paypal.api.payments.Payment.get(accessToken, paymentId) fails and returns the following error:

> Response Code : 500 with response : {"name":"DATA_RETRIEVAL","message":"Error retrieving data","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#DATA_RETRIEVAL","debug_id":"b42c7f5c2b97d"}

A couple more debug ids in case they help: 04870b7c20522, 9cc4393ce08b1, 3d3eb3b9109e0.

The information link only contains another error message.

> ("Service Temporarily Unavailable - The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.")

Does anyone have an idea why this fails on the App Engine? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also face the same problem using Payment::all() functions inside rest-api-sdk-php library from PayPal. It works in their sample application but not in my sandbox. I also check it inside LIVE environment, and it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal seems to have fixed the problem.